# C++ and RLE for sequences of symbols

Tags: c++, run-length-encoding

I have difficulties with how to use RLE on sequences of symbols.

For example, I can do RLE encoding on strings like

```
"ASSSAAAEERRRRRRRR"
```

which will be transformed to:

```
"A1S3A3E2R8".
```

But I'd like to perform RLE on strings like

```
"XXXYYYYY(1ADEFC)(EDCADD)(1ADEFC)(1ADEFC)(1ADEFC)"
```

which will be transformed to:

```
"X3Y5(1ADEFC)1(EDCADD)1(1ADEFC)3"
```

Is there is a way to reach it? This job becomes a bit easer because long strings always follows in brackets. Could give an advice to do this in C++?
If there is a better way to store values than using brackets, it will be also great if you recommend me.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Compress the data?

Comment: Yes, I try to compress text files that contains colors of pixels from image. I'd like to use RLE on these files. After RLE I can use gzip compression on those files to achieve better compression.

Comment: You are quite likely to find that `gzip` is already good at detecting and compressing repeating patterns, as well are repeating symbols. That's basically what the LZ77 algorithm does, and LZ77 is the first step of `gzip` compression.

Comment: Yes, I've already done it using only gzip, but size is still too big. For example, I've created a file that contains colors of white image ~2700x4000 pixels, and it has weight about 10,7 MiB. If I use only gzip, it has weight about 100 KiB, but if I do RLE first and then RLE, it has weight about 0,5 KiB.

Comment: Fair enough. Well done for performing the tests.

Comment: Oh, error. RLE first and gzip compression then. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should break down this problem into smaller parts. First, you should have a function that tokenizes your stream and returns each individual part. For this example input stream:

```
"XXXYYYYY(1ADEFC)(EDCADD)(1ADEFC)(1ADEFC)(1ADEFC)"
```

this function will return the following elements, one per call:

```
X
X
X
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
(1ADEFC)
(EDCADD)
(1ADEFC)
(1ADEFC)
(1ADEFC)
<eof>
```

If you get this function correctly implemented, then the RLE algorithm that you already implemented for single characters should be easily adapted to support longer strings.

Comment: All ingenious is simple. :-) Thanks, I'll follow this way!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention your intention is to RLE encode the data to later use gzip compression and achieve better compression, my answer is don't bother encoding it first. gzip compression uses DEFLATE, which is a generalization of run-length encoding that can take advantage of runs of strings of characters. You won't get better compression for applying the same algorithm twice, and in fact you may even loose compression a bit.

If you insist in performing your own RLE, then it may be better to store the set length instead of using parenthesis. That is, instead of `(1ADEFC)3` use `61ADEFC3`. Also note that you intend to compress pixels, which use the full range of byte values. Keep that in mind, as an algorithm written to work with strings would not be appropiate for raw data with embedded nulls and non-printable characters all around.

Comment: It has difference. After I've used RLE algorythm and after that gzip compression, there was a really big difference. I did it on file that contains only 2700x4000 "Y" symbols, but it's only the example.

Comment: @ghostmansd: You should be careful drawing conclusions from such trivial tests... algorithms often ignore degenerate cases that never occur in actual use in favor of better performance with more typical data.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Such files will always be generated from normal images and will have magic numbers, so errors are minimal.

Comment: @ghostmansd: But a "normal image" won't have ten-million copies of the same pixel.  That's what I'm trying to say... do you get similar results from inputs that represent actual use, or just from degenerate cases like that?

Comment: @dennis-zickefoose: Ah, I understood. Yes, there is not a big chance to get full-white images, but some of images (for example, bitonal scans of books) however have large sequences of white color. It can be usable, I think.